# jQuery AJAX-script not working in Firefox

Tags: php, jquery

I can't figure out why this script won't work in Firefox. And, even though my `ajax_loadmore.php`  outputs FALSE, it still makes the AJAX-call (in Chrome).

```
var request;
$(window).scroll(function () {
   if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height() ) {
      var ID = $('.stbody:last').attr('id').match(/stbody(\d+)/)[1];
      $('#loader').show();

      if(request) {
        return
      }
      request = $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "ajax_loadmore.php?lCom="+ID,
        success: function(result) {
            if(result!='FALSE') {
                $('#loader').hide();
                $('#moreComments').append(result);
                $(".oembed").oembed(null, {
                    embedMethod: "fill",
                    maxWidth: 700,
                    maxHeight: 600
                });
                request = null;
            } else {
                $('#loader').hide();
                $('#moreComments').html('<center><p>Slut på inlägg</p></center>');
                request = null;
            }
        }
      }); 
   }
});
```

`ajax_loadmore.php` code:

```
<?php
if($_GET['lCom']) {
  include_once 'core/init.php';
  protect_page();
  include_once 'includes/db.php';
  include_once 'includes/functions.php';
  include_once 'includes/tolink.php';
  include_once 'includes/time_stamp.php';
  include_once 'session.php';

  $lCom = $_GET['lCom'];
  $Wall = new Wall_Updates();
  $updatesarray=$Wall->Updates_more($uid,$lCom);
  if(!empty($updatesarray)) {

    foreach($updatesarray as $data) {
      $msg_id=$data['msg_id'];
      $orimessage=$data['message'];
      $message=tolink(htmlspecialchars(nl2br($data['message'])));
      $time=$data['created'];
      $username=$data['username'];
      $uid=$data['uid_fk'];
      $face=get_profile_pic($uid,'small');
      $face2=get_profile_pic($session_user_id,'mini'); 
      $commentsarray=$Wall->Comments($msg_id);
      ?>

        //HTMLSTUFF HERE.. 

      <?php
      }
  } else { echo 'FALSE'; }
} else { die('du ska inte vara här..'); }

?>
```

Comment: Does Firefox throw an error?  What version of Firefox?  What is the script supposed to do?  What does it do?

Comment: You have an extra comma after `maxHeight: 600,`  just fyi

Comment: Have you tried debugging with firebug?

Comment: Firefox does not throw an error in console. It is a script built to fetch more comments, like an infinite scroll.. It works in Chrome. I'm using Firefox 13 btw.

Comment: I added the HTML in the post above.

Answer (score 0):

I was also faced with the same problem, and I used the script from the following link:

http://www.9lessons.info/2009/07/load-data-while-scroll-with-jquery-php.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work now. I use jQuery to add a sticky class to my menu when it reaches the top. And that menu had position: relative on it wich probably messed with the height of the window or something so that Firefox didn't execute the script because it didn't reach the bottom.

When I changed the position: relative on the menu container to position: absolute it just worked.

If someone can explain why this is in more detail I would be happy! (because it worked in Chrome and IE I'm guessing its a rendering issue in Firefox)

Thanks for your replies!